# Changing WATER to STEAM

Tags: no-computers, word-ladder

How do you change the word **Water**  to the word **Steam** by changing one letter at a time? The newly formed words must be from Merriam Webster dictionary. No proper nouns, abbreviations or acronyms. No rearranging of the letters either.

**Note**: I myself could not find an answer to this question. May be because I missed something simple or I am just not that good!! Or both. But many of you are and I am expecting that there is a 10 step or less answer.

I asked Meta for advice and @Rand Al'Thor pointed me to another similar question which essentially said you can ask a question with no answer found by yourself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one list of 10 words

> water
>  later
>  layer
>  sayer
>  shyer
>  sheer
>  steer
>  steed
>  stead
>  steam

Here are some definitions/examples for some of the words.

> SAYER: one that says. example: he is a sayer rather than a doer.
>  SHYER: more shy.  example: he is shyer than anyone else in his class.
>  SHEER: of very thin or transparent texture : fine and light in weight.  example: a sheer summer dress
>  --OR--
>  SHEER: utter, absolute. example: frightened by the sheer immensity of the place. 
>  STEER: to direct the course of. example: to steer a car (using the steering wheel). 
>  STEED: a horse. example: "...summoning his steed ere the darkness failed..." (from LotR)

Comment: Ninja'd! I like your answer better anyway.

Comment: Great @SteveV. I stand by my statement. I missed "Shyer". I am just not that good!!

Comment: Lol ... these might be "pretty common" for native English speakers, but I never used the words "sayer" "shyer" "sheer" "steer" "steed" in my life - that's half of the ten words ^^|| Not complaining about the answer, but just expressing my feeling of cultural difference here. This kind of puzzles look hopeless for non-native English speakers like me.

Comment: @WhatsUp sorry :( i'll put some more info

Answer (score 6):

Here's one answer with 10 steps...and one word I'm not too happy with:

> WATER
>  LATER
>  LAYER
>  PAYER
>  [PLYER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plyer)
>  SLYER
>  [SLEER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleer)
>  STEER
>  STEEL
>  STEAL
>  STEAM

Answer (score 0):

Managed one with 8 steps, a questionable word (with a merriam-webster definition), and the assumption that changing a letter could also mean insertion/deletion.

> WATER
>  [WATE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wate)
>  SATE
>  STATE
>  STARE
>  STAR
>  STEAR
>  STEAM

Comment: Usually in [word-ladder] puzzles, if you can add/remove letters, that is explicitly stated.

Comment: Just checking...can you please verify STEAR is a word, vice a prefix? That would shorten both my and @SteveV's answers by a step.

Comment: @JeremyDover, for what it's worth, I found [this site](https://www.wordsense.eu/stear/) claiming it as an obsolete form of "steer"